# Pipes inside backticks fail under MinGW

Tags: bash, mingw

When I try to run some Bash scripts on a Windows XP machine using MinGW, I get the following error:

```
./autogen.sh: pipe error: No such file or directory
```

I have localised the problem to Bash lines such as the following, which have a pipe inside backticks:

```
__copyright="`grep Copyright ./autogen.sh | head -1`"
```

However, pipes not inside backticks work just fine:

```
grep Copyright ./autogen.sh | head -1
```

All the programs you expect (sh, head, grep) are available and run happily on the command line and in Bash.

What should I do to resolve this error? I cannot run most Bash build tools without it.

Comment: I am curious if changing the `` to $() will fix anything: [Why is $(...) preferred over `...` (backticks)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082).  Does this fix anything?

Comment: No, that still results in "pipe error".

Comment: As an aside, you don't need quotes around assignments. `var=\`foo bar\`` is perfectly ok

Comment: I know, but that's what the source file has, and it should still work as it is valid syntax. The problem still occurs without them, for what it's worth.

Comment: Version information of MSYS, BASH?  I cannot reproduce the problem with the MSYS I have.

Comment: On `GNU bash, version 4.4.19(2)-release-(x86_64-pc-msys)` (`Git for Windows v2.18.0`), ``T=`echo 1 |cat`; echo $T`` outputs nothing

Answer (score 2):

```
$ msysinfo | head -3
msysinfo-1.3: Send this to the MSYS support list:

MSYS 1.0.11(0.46/3/2) 2004-04-30 18:55 i686 unknown; targ=MINGW32

$ echo '__copyright="`grep Copyright ./autogen.sh | head -1`" && echo $__copyright' >test.sh

$ cat test.sh 
__copyright="`grep Copyright ./autogen.sh | head -1`" && echo $__copyright

$ sh test.sh
# Copyright 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008 by
```

For this test, I copied autogen.sh from some place like... randomly... http://svn.ghostscript.com/ghostscript/tags/freetype-2.3.7/autogen.sh

Probably this means your question needs more information.

But... sometimes when I run into snarly scenarios, it can help to enclose the breaking code in `(  )`.  Technically, also, you do not need `" "` around backticks, and that complicates some use, but your example does not seem problematic.

I really hate to propose the following as it seems completely unnecessary:

```
$ for item in `grep Copyright ./autogen.sh`;
  do
    __copyright="$__copyright $item";
  done;
  echo $__copyright
```

What is more weird is that your error message seems to imply autogen.sh itself generated the error as though autogen.sh was grepping itself so I did:

```
$ sh test.sh
__copyright="`grep Copyright ./test.sh | head -1`" && echo $__copyright
```

after modifying test.sh to grep itself, and even that worked.

It therefore sounds like a sequencing issue and not a backtick issue, you know, which came first, the chicken or the egg?

Is autogen.sh trying to read its own Copyright comment?  One way to let comments serve as data is to wrap them in here documents:

```
_Copyright ()
{
  cat <<-END_OF_TEXT
# Copyright 2012, me
END_OF_TEXT
}

_Copyright
```

Comment: While I know the syntax may not be optimal, I didn't write this script and I don't think converting all the scripts is practical for me. The script is reading its own source file, but that seems to cause no problem on a Linux machine running real Bash. Additionally, this error happens on _every_ pipe-within-backtick statement, not just this one. This is several hundred lines in just this script, so it indicates a rather fundamental problem.

Comment: All the examples in this answer were done in MSYS ... indicating back ticks work just fine on the indicated system.  Various scenarios were set up to try to reproduce the failure and none were found.  Without being able to reproduce the problem, there's not much to do.  What version of MSYS, BASH, etc?